# Mapping URLs with mod rewrite

Tags: regex, apache

I migrated my site to a new platform & I want to map old URLs like this:
anecdotage.com/index.php?aid=13337
to this:
anecdotage.com/articles/13336/
[Note the offset of one in the IDs]

Can I do this in apache's mod_rewrite. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can't do any math with mod_rewrite by itself, meaning you can match against `13337` and do something to it to change it to `13336` without employing some kind of `[RewriteMap](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap) to externally subtract a number by 1, but this requires access to either server or vhost config.

So in the vhost/server config you have to setup the map:

```
RewriteMap subtract prg:/path/to/script/that/subtracts-by-one.sh
```

This `subtracts-by-one.sh` script takes a number as an input, subtracts 1 from it, then prints out the result. Then to use it in a rewrite rule:

```
# to make sure we aren't clobbering legit requests
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} aid=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^/?index.php$ /articles/${subtract:%1}/? [L]
```

If you don't have access to rewrite maps, then you'll need to do it the hard way and enumerate all of your rewrites:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} aid=12345
RewriteRule ^/?index.php$ /articles/12344/? [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} aid=13337
RewriteRule ^/?index.php$ /articles/13336/? [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} aid=19911
RewriteRule ^/?index.php$ /articles/19910/? [L]
```

etc.